R ggplot2 need custom legend to have less values than corresponding line plot values to avoid duplicates
I have data which looks like the following:
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

dat<-tibble(
  group =  c(rep("Group 1", 10), rep("Group 2", 10), rep("Group 3", 10)),
  iter = rep(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)), 3),
  group_iter = paste(group, iter, sep = "_"),
  x = 1:30,
  y = 11:40
)
 # A tibble: 30 × 5
   group    iter group_iter     x     y
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>      <int> <int>
 1 Group 1     1 Group 1_1      1    11
 2 Group 1     1 Group 1_1      2    12
 3 Group 1     1 Group 1_1      3    13
 4 Group 1     1 Group 1_1      4    14
 5 Group 1     1 Group 1_1      5    15
 6 Group 1     2 Group 1_2      6    16
 7 Group 1     2 Group 1_2      7    17
 8 Group 1     2 Group 1_2      8    18
 9 Group 1     2 Group 1_2      9    19
10 Group 1     2 Group 1_2     10    20
# ℹ 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more row

Where values in group are repeated by iteration and produce corresponding x and y outcomes. I am attempting to use ggplot2 to produce the following line graph:
groups<-dat%>%distinct(group_iter, .keep_all = T)%>%pull(group)
uniqe_groups<-length(groups)
color_vals<-brewer.pal(uniqe_groups, name = "Set1")
color_vals1<-tibble(group = groups)%>%
  left_join(
    tibble(group = unique(dat$group), color = color_vals),
    by = "group"
  )%>%pull(color)

dat%>%ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y, color = group_iter, fill = group_iter)) + geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual("", labels = groups, values = color_vals1)


The catch, however, is that I need the legend to not have duplicated Group values. So for example, the legend in the previous plot would look like this:

The problem I am having is I can't seem to find a good way to customize the legend like this (i.e., less legend values using scale_color_manual than color/fill in the plot) without either not having the correct number of lines or producing an error:
error in `palette()`: ! insufficient values in manual scale

I have search fairly throughly on StackOverlow and other sources:
ggplot2 Error: Insufficient values in manual scale
Fixing Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided. In R
How to add manual colors for a ggplot2 (geom_smooth/geom_line)
ggplot2 custom legend shapes
but none of them seem to solve this specifc problem. Help desperately needed please and thank you!

I don't think your code runs as is. (At least it didn't for me, when you create the 2nd tibble to join to. tibbles, unlike data.frames, only recycle "values of size one," so you'd need data.frame(group = unique(dat$group), color = color_vals) there, since the group vector is 3 items and the color vector is 6 items as is. Maybe you meant uniqe_groups<-length(unique(groups))?)

You don't need to fuss with the groups or color_vals. Just call: ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, color = group, fill = group_iter)) +    geom_line()

This will achieve what you want:
library(tibble)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- tibble(
  group =  c(rep("Group 1", 10), rep("Group 2", 10), rep("Group 3", 10)),
  iter = rep(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)), 3),
  group_iter = paste(group, iter, sep = "_"),
  x = 1:30,
  y = 11:40
)

groups <- unique(dat$group)

color_vals <- brewer.pal(length(groups), name = "Set1")

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = group, group = group_iter)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual("", labels = groups, values = color_vals)


